# android mapBox java.lang.Exception: Last location unavailable

Tags: android, kotlin, location, mapbox-android

Integrated mapbox in android.On some devices theres no problem and on some other devices  the current location is not being set.It just shows a black screen for mapView.In the devices that not showing the current location in the mapview the Logcat logs this  **java.lang.Exception: Last location unavailable**.Tested in oreo - two devices(in Xiaomi it's showing but in samsung its not) Nougat(HUAWEI DRA-LX2 ) not showing.Thanks in advance.

```
class HomeFragment : BaseFragment() {

@Inject
lateinit var factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory
lateinit var binding: HomeBinding
var anchorClicked: Boolean = false
private lateinit var mapboxMap: MapboxMap
private lateinit var locationEngine: LocationEngine

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    binding = inflater.bind(R.layout.fragment_home, container)
    return binding.root
}

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    binding.handler = this
    binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
    binding.mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val navigationView: NavigationView = requireActivity().findViewById(R.id.sideNV)
    val headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0)
    withViewModel<MapViewModel>(factory) {
        binding.mapView.getMapAsync { mapBoxMap ->
            this@HomeFragment.mapboxMap = mapBoxMap
            if (getCurrentTheme())
                mapBoxMap.setStyle(Style.TRAFFIC_NIGHT) {
                    requestPermission(it)
                }
            else mapBoxMap.setStyle(Style.TRAFFIC_DAY) {
                requestPermission(it)
            }
        }
        val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        if (auth.currentUser != null) {
            val auth1 = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
            if (auth1.currentUser != null) {
                headerView.userNameTV.text = auth1.currentUser?.displayName
                headerView.userEmailTV.text = auth1.currentUser?.email.toString()
                Glide.with(requireActivity())
                    .load(auth1.currentUser?.photoUrl)
                    .apply(RequestOptions.bitmapTransform(RoundedCorners(14)))
                    .into(headerView.userPicIV)
            }
        }
        binding.vm = this
        getCountries().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { })
    }
}

fun onAnchor() {
    var valueAnimator = ValueAnimator()
    valueAnimator = if (anchorClicked) {
        ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0.5f, 0.75f)
    } else {
        ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0.75f, 0.5f)
    }
    valueAnimator.duration = 500
    valueAnimator.interpolator = AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()
    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener { valueAnimator ->
        val lp = binding.guideline.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
        // get the float value
        lp.guidePercent = valueAnimator.animatedValue as Float
        // update layout params
        binding.guideline.layoutParams = lp
    }
    valueAnimator.start()
    anchorClicked = !anchorClicked
}

fun requestPermission(style: Style) {
    if (!hasPermissions(context!!, permissions)) requestPermissions(permissions, RC_LOCATION)
    else enableLocationComponent(style)
}

private fun enableLocationComponent(loadedMapStyle: Style) {
    val customLocationComponentOptions = LocationComponentOptions.builder(context!!)
        .trackingGesturesManagement(true)
        .accuracyColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.com_facebook_blue))
        .build()

    val locationComponentActivationOptions =
        LocationComponentActivationOptions.builder(context!!, loadedMapStyle)
            .locationComponentOptions(customLocationComponentOptions)
            .build()

    mapboxMap.locationComponent.apply {
        activateLocationComponent(locationComponentActivationOptions)
        isLocationComponentEnabled = true
        cameraMode = CameraMode.TRACKING
        renderMode = RenderMode.COMPASS
    }
}


override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    permissions: Array<out String>,
    grantResults: IntArray
) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    if (requestCode == RC_LOCATION) {
        if (grantResults.isNotEmpty()
            && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            enableLocationComponent(mapboxMap.style!!)
        }
    }
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    mapView.onResume()
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    mapView?.onStart()
}

override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    mapView?.onStop()
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    mapView?.onPause()
}

override fun onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory()
    mapView?.onLowMemory()
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    mapView?.onDestroy()
}

companion object {
    const val RC_LOCATION = 10
}
}
```